# Coloring bitmap with java

Tags: android

Hi I am creating an app for android and I encountered a problem with how to color bitmaps
I am using the following simple code

```
for(int i=0;i<pixels.length;i++){
          if(pixels[i] == COLOR.WHITE){
           pixels[i]=Color.RED;
        }
 }
```

Where pixels is the array of pixels of the bitmap 
However the problem is that I'm getting in the edges of the colored area a thin layer of pixels that weren't colored I  understand this stems from that this layer of white is somewhat shadowy(not entirely white partially black) how do I get over this? 
Hope I made my question clear enough

Comment: Does your bitmap contain transparency?

Comment: It contains only solid colors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you are matching and replacing one specific integer value for white. However, in your original bitmap that white color bleeds into other colors and therefore you have white color values around the edges of these white patches that are slightly different.

You need to change your algorithm to take a color matching tolerance into account. For that you'll have to split up your pixel and your key color into their three color channels and check them individually if the differences between them are within a certain tolerance value.

That way you can match these whitish colored pixels around the edges. But even with added tolerance you cannot just replace your matching pixels just with red. You would get aliased hard, red edges and it wouldn't look pretty. I wrote a similar algorithm a while ago and got around that aliasing issue by doing some color blending in HSV color space:

```
public Bitmap changeColor(Bitmap src, int keyColor,
            int replColor, int tolerance) {
        Bitmap copy = src.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        int width = copy.getWidth();
        int height = copy.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        int sR = Color.red(keyColor);
        int sG = Color.green(keyColor);
        int sB = Color.blue(keyColor);
        int tR = Color.red(replColor);
        int tG = Color.green(replColor);
        int tB = Color.blue(replColor);
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.RGBToHSV(tR, tG, tB, hsv);
        float targetHue = hsv[0];
        float targetSat = hsv[1];
        float targetVal = hsv[2];

        for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; ++i) {
            int pixel = pixels[i];

            if(pixel == keyColor) {
                pixels[i] = replColor;
            } else {
                int pR = Color.red(pixel);
                int pG = Color.green(pixel);
                int pB = Color.blue(pixel);

                int deltaR = Math.abs(pR - sR);
                int deltaG = Math.abs(pG - sG);
                int deltaB = Math.abs(pB - sB);

                if(deltaR <= tolerance && deltaG <= tolerance
                        && deltaB <= tolerance) {
                    Color.RGBToHSV(pR, pG, pB, hsv);
                    hsv[0] = targetHue;
                    hsv[1] = targetSat;
                    hsv[2] *= targetVal;

                    int mixTrgColor = Color.HSVToColor(Color.alpha(pixel),
                            hsv);
                    pixels[i] = mixTrgColor;
                }
            }
        }

        copy.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        return copy;
    }
```

keyColor and replColor are ARGB encoded integer values such as Color.WHITE and Color.RED. tolerance is a value from 0 to 255 that specifies the key color matching tolerance per color channel. I had to rewrite that snippet a bit to remove framework specifics. I hope I didn't make any mistakes.

As a word of warning: Java (on Android) is pretty slow with image processing. If it's not fast enough for you, you should rewrite the algorithm in C for example and use the NDK.

**UPDATE: Color replace algorithm in C**

Here is the implementation of the same algorithm written in C. The last function is the actual algorithm which takes the bitmap's pixel array as argument. You need to create a header file with that function declaration and set up some NDK compilation boilerplate and create an additional Java class with the following method declaration:

```
native static void changeColor(int[] pixels, int width, int height, int keyColor, int replColor, int tolerance);
```

C implementation:

```
#include <math.h>

#define MIN(x,y) ((x < y) ? x : y)
#define MAX(x,y) ((x > y) ? x : y)

int clamp_byte(int val) {
    if(val > 255) {
        return 255;
    } else if(val < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return val;
    }
}

int encode_argb(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b, uint8_t a) {
    return ((a & 0xFF) << 24) | ((r & 0xFF) << 16) | ((g & 0xFF) << 8) | (b & 0xFF);
}

int alpha(int c) {
    return (c >> 24) & 0xFF;
}

int red(int c) {
    return (c >> 16) & 0xFF;
}

int green(int c) {
    return (c >> 8) & 0xFF;
}

int blue(int c) {
    return c & 0xFF;
}

typedef struct struct_hsv {
    uint16_t h;
    uint8_t s;
    uint8_t v;
} hsv;

// http://www.ruinelli.ch/rgb-to-hsv
hsv rgb255_to_hsv(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b) {
    uint8_t min, max, delta;
    hsv result;
    int h;

    min = MIN(r, MIN(g, b));
    max = MAX(r, MAX(g, b));

    result.v = max; // v, 0..255
    delta = max - min; // 0..255, < v

    if(delta != 0 && max != 0) {
        result.s = ((int) delta) * 255 / max; // s, 0..255

        if(r == max) {
            h = (g - b) * 60 / delta; // between yellow & magenta
        } else if(g == max) {
            h = 120 + (b - r) * 60 / delta; // between cyan & yellow
        } else {
            h = 240 + (r - g) * 60 / delta; // between magenta & cyan
        }

        if(h < 0) h += 360;

        result.h = h;
    } else {
        // r = g = b = 0
        result.h = 0;
        result.s = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int hsv_to_argb(hsv color, uint8_t alpha) {
    int i;
    uint8_t r,g,b;
    float f, p, q, t, h, s, v;

    h = (float) color.h;
    s = (float) color.s;
    v = (float) color.v;

    s /= 255;

    if(s == 0) {
        // achromatic (grey)
        return encode_argb(color.v, color.v, color.v, alpha);
    }

    h /= 60; // sector 0 to 5
    i = floor(h);
    f = h - i; // factorial part of h
    p = (unsigned char) (v * (1 - s));
    q = (unsigned char) (v * (1 - s * f));
    t = (unsigned char) (v * (1 - s * (1 - f)));

    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            r = v;
            g = t;
            b = p;
            break;
        case 1:
            r = q;
            g = v;
            b = p;
            break;
        case 2:
            r = p;
            g = v;
            b = t;
            break;
        case 3:
            r = p;
            g = q;
            b = v;
            break;
        case 4:
            r = t;
            g = p;
            b = v;
            break;
        default: // case 5:
            r = v;
            g = p;
            b = q;
            break;
    }

    return encode_argb(r, g, b, alpha);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_package_name_ClassName_changeColor(
        JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jintArray bitmapArray, jint width, jint height,
        jint keyColor, jint replColor, jint tolerance) {
    jint* pixels = (*env)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(env, bitmapArray, 0);
    int sR = red(keyColor);
    int sG = green(keyColor);
    int sB = blue(keyColor);
    int tR = red(replColor);
    int tG = green(replColor);
    int tB = blue(replColor);
    hsv cHsv = rgb255_to_hsv(tR, tG, tB);
    int targetHue = cHsv.h;
    int targetSat = cHsv.s;
    int targetVal = cHsv.v;
    int i;
    int max = width * height;

    for(i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        int pixel = pixels[i];

        if(pixel == keyColor) {
            pixels[i] = replColor;
        } else {
            int pR = red(pixel);
            int pG = green(pixel);
            int pB = blue(pixel);

            int deltaR = abs(pR - sR);
            int deltaG = abs(pG - sG);
            int deltaB = abs(pB - sB);

            if(deltaR <= tolerance && deltaG <= tolerance
                    && deltaB <= tolerance) {
                cHsv = rgb255_to_hsv(pR, pG, pB);
                cHsv.h = targetHue;
                cHsv.s = targetSat;
                int newValue = ((int) cHsv.v * targetVal) / 255;
                cHsv.v = newValue;

                int mixTrgColor = hsv_to_argb(cHsv, alpha(pixel));
                pixels[i] = mixTrgColor;
            }
        }
    }

    (*env)->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(env, bitmapArray, pixels, 0);
}
```

Comment: This looks great can you give me some references to algorithms in C which work fast enough? (not openCV)  because the time might be an issue

Comment: @user2900110 I updated my answer and provided you with the same implementation written in C. It makes exclusive use of integers which is much faster on most ARM processors than crunching floating point values.

Comment: Thanks you've done all the work for me also I've managed to solve my problem in a rather crude way which is to color every pixel with the ones around him all in all it's pretty useful although I think I'll go with your solution